# ASP.NET can not find DevExpress.XtraCharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, devexpress

I'm working on ASP.NET project and I need to draw a point chart in my project, I choosed to use DevExpress to do this job. So, I've tried to use one of this two examples: [example 1](https://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/PointAndLineViewTypes/PointSeries.aspx), [example 2](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument15894), but I'm getting this problem:  `The type or namespace name 'XtraCharts' does not exist in the namespace 'DevExpress' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Ps: I've worked with DevExpress before in Windows Form, and I used exmple 2 and I didn't get any problem.
How can I fix it?

Comment: The error suggest you haven't got the appropriate DLLs in your project

Comment: I know, how can I add it ?

Comment: You'll need to install DevExpress on your machine. If I remeber correctly DevExpress is a paid feature

Comment: It's already installed, I worked with it before. DevExpress.XtraCharts works  in Windows Form correctly, but not in a ASP.NET project.

Comment: In that case. Right click on Reference in your project > Add Reference. Reference Manager window will pop up. Under Assemblies click on Extensions then scroll through the list and select the appropriate DLL you want and click ok

Comment: done, it works!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll add it as an answer so it benefits others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you will need to add the appropriate DLL. To do so you'll have to do the following:

1. Right click on Reference in your project
2. Then click on Add Reference
3. The Reference Manager window will popup
4. Expand the Assemblies Node and choose Extensions
5. Scroll through the list and choose the correct DevExress DLL in your case `XtraCharts`
6. Click on OK